# Transition Maps of Regular Surfaces are Smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

> Let $S$ be a regular surface, and let $\phi:U\to S$ and $\psi:V\to S$ be charts of $S$. The transition map $\psi^{-1}\circ \phi$ is smooth.

Here is part of the proof:

> Since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are charts, it follows by definition that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth. It suffices to show that $\psi^{-1}$ is smooth.
>
> Claim: There exists an open neighborhood $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ of $\mathbf{q}\in \phi^{-1}(U\cap V)$ such that $\psi^{-1}\circ \phi|_{D}$ is smooth.
>
> Let $\mathbf{r}=\psi^{-1}(\phi(\mathbf{q}))\in \psi^{-1}(U\cap V)$. By the regularity condition for charts, $d_{r}\psi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is injective.
>
> Let $\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\mathbf{e}_{2}\right\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Set $\mathbf{f}_{1}=d_{r}\psi(\mathbf{e}_{1})$ and $\mathbf{f}_{2}=d_{r}\psi(\mathbf{e}_{2})$ as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Since $d_{r}\psi$ is injective, $\left\{\mathbf{f}_{1},\mathbf{f}_{2}\right\}$ is linearly independent. Then $\mathbf{f}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{f}_{2}$ are tangent to the surface $S$, and $\left\{\mathbf{f}_{1},\mathbf{f}_{2},\mathbf{f}_{1}\times \mathbf{f}_{2}\right\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
>
> Define $F:\psi^{-1}(U\cap V)\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ by
>
> \begin{align*}
>     F(x,y,z)=\psi(x,y)+z\mathbf{f}_{1}\times \mathbf{f}_{2}.
> \end{align*}
> Then $F=\psi$ when $z=0$. Let $(r,0)\in \psi^{-1}(U\cap V)\times \mathbb{R}$.

Before using the inverse function theorem, I need to show that $d_{(r,0)}F$ is invertible. I am not sure how to directly calculate this matrix, since $F$ is not written explicitly as a vector. Any idea how to show this?

Comment: Write the matrix using the standard basis in the domain and the basis $\{f_1, f_2, f_1\times f_2\}$ in the range.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you give me more of a hint? I don't understand how to use two bases to construct a matrix.

Comment: If you have a linear map $T\colon V\to W$ and bases $\{v_j\}$ and $\{w_i\}$ for $V$ and $W$ respectively, you consider the matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ given by $T(v_j) = \sum a_{ij}w_i$.